# Docker COPY error when copying files from host to container

Tags: scala, docker, dockerfile

In the following Dockerfile I'm trying to copy a jar file from a location on the host into the container, but seems Docker does not like it as I guess I'm missing something. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:jdk8
MAINTAINER joesan

ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.15
ENV CHECKSUM 18b106d09b2874f2a538c6e1f6b20c565885b2a8051428bd6d630fb92c1c0f96

ENV APP_NAME my-app
ENV PROJECT_HOME /opt/apps

RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_HOME/$APP_NAME

# Copy the jar file
COPY ./target/scala-*/my-app-*.jar $PROJECT_HOME/$APP_NAME

# Copy the database file
COPY .my-db.mv.db $PROJECT_HOME/$APP_NAME

# Run the application
CMD ["$PROJECT_HOME/$APP_NAME java -Denv=dev -jar my-app-*.jar"]
```

In my build pipeline, I could see the following error message:

```
Step 8/10 : COPY ./target/scala-*/my-app-*.jar $PROJECT_HOME/$APP_NAME
COPY failed: no source files were specified
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED                  SIZE
<none>                <none>              4a240742a379        Less than a second ago   171MB
anapsix/alpine-java   jdk8                ed55c27d366d        3 years ago              171MB
Error response from daemon: No such image: [secure]
Pushing image [secure] to repository hub.docker.com
The push refers to repository [docker.io/[secure]/my-app]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: [secure]/my-app
```

What is that I'm missing and how could I debug this? I mean I could add some echo statements to print out the path, but I'm not sure why I face this error!

Comment: It says no source files specified, maybe nothing matched ./target/scala-*/my-app-*.jar

Comment: Is the Dockerfile sits beside the target folder?

Comment: Yes it does sit beside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the target folder is not in `"./"` folder. which can be because it's ignored by `.dockerignore` file or the build context is not pointing to the parent folder of the target folder.

In case you are not familiar with build context, it's explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage)